# I need PowerShell script to read and increment value inside json file everytime after checkout i.e. value": "AEU-EHSSAS19" should change AEU-EHSSAS20

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "APORIA"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "value": "Password@1234"
    },
    "VMName": {
      "value": "AEU-EHSSAS19"
    },
    "VMSize": {
      "value": "Standard_B2ms"
    },
    "LabName": {
      "value": "EUW-TSE-D-SELFSERV"
    },
      "windowsOSVersion": {
      "value": "2016-Datacenter"
    }     
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried **yourself** already. If you received error messages, post them in your question too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PowerShell script to read and increment value inside json file everytime after checkout

Refer to the following PowerShell script:

```
$pathToJson = "path/test.json"
$a = Get-Content $pathToJson | ConvertFrom-Json

$VMName = $a.parameters.VMName.value
echo $VMname
$len = $VMName.Length
$number= "$VMName".Substring($len - 2, 2)
echo $number

$number = [int]$number+1

echo $number

$NewVMName = $VMName.replace('19',$number)

echo $NewVMName

$a.parameters.VMName.value = $NewVMName

$a | ConvertTo-Json | set-content $pathToJson
```

The PowerShell script will find the value of the **VMName** field. And then it will get the number of in the string and Increment +1.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin I am looking for above code only